# How do I change my checkbox colours on the following page?

Tags: css, ag-grid

I'm trying to adapt some code from the following page:

https://plnkr.co/edit/plSzOtlpPXFguBIY1JwB?p=preview

When I click 'Column', the checkboxes are pink.

The style seems controlled as follows:

```
<style> html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; } </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto"/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-enterprise@18.1.1/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.min.js"></script></head>
<body>

<div id="myGrid" style="height: 100%;" class="ag-theme-material"></div>
```

I'm trying to follow and trace the .css but I'm having trouble doing so.

How would I, for example, change the checkboxes to blue?

Comment: Open up the developer tools in your browser and inspect the checkboxes. You can then see the CSS rules. Unfortunately it appears that the pink is a background-image, so you won't be able to simply update the colour in the CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to follow and trace the .css but I'm having trouble doing
>   so.
>
> How would I, for example, change the checkboxes to blue?

Here's how to do this using Chrome's Developer Tools:

- Inspect a checked checkbox: `<span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-checked"></span>`
- Look for this CSS in the styles panel:

  ```
  .ag-theme-material .ag-icon-checkbox-checked:empty {
      background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTgiIGhlaWdodD0iMTgiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxOCAxOCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj48cGF0aCBkPSJNMTYgMEgyYTIgMiAwIDAgMC0yIDJ2MTRhMiAyIDAgMCAwIDIgMmgxNGEyIDIgMCAwIDAgMi0yVjJhMiAyIDAgMCAwLTItMnpNNyAxNEwyIDlsMS40MS0xLjQxTDcgMTEuMTdsNy41OS03LjU5TDE2IDVsLTkgOXoiIGZpbGw9IiNGRjQwODEiLz48L3N2Zz4=);
  }
  ```
- Right-click the underlined `data:image...` part, click "Open in new tab".
- In the new tab, right-click "View page source".
- Here's your SVG (formatted):

  ```
  <svg width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
      <path
          d="M16 0H2a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v14a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h14a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2zM7 14L2 9l1.41-1.41L7 11.17l7.59-7.59L16 5l-9 9z"
          fill="#FF4081"
      />
  </svg>
  ```
- You need to change the `fill` to the desired colour. I went for `#1976D2` (`blue[700]`).
- You can just save the SVG file and point to that in the CSS if you want to. Otherwise, here's how to get it back as a data URI.
- Put your SVG into some random web tool. You don't particularly have to use base64 these days for SVG, but I'm not going to get in to that.
- I used this one: https://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php
- Put the output in the original CSS:

  ```
  .ag-theme-material .ag-icon-checkbox-checked:empty {
      background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTgiIGhlaWdodD0iMTgiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxOCAxOCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj48cGF0aCBkPSJNMTYgMEgyYTIgMiAwIDAgMC0yIDJ2MTRhMiAyIDAgMCAwIDIgMmgxNGEyIDIgMCAwIDAgMi0yVjJhMiAyIDAgMCAwLTItMnpNNyAxNEwyIDlsMS40MS0xLjQxTDcgMTEuMTdsNy41OS03LjU5TDE2IDVsLTkgOXoiIGZpbGw9IiMxOTc2RDIiLz48L3N2Zz4=);
  }
  ```
- Put this new CSS somewhere in your code. It must be after the original ag-grid CSS.
- The end: https://plnkr.co/edit/BuxqByk5Py0vW0qUfPbx?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

They are not using real checkboxes, see the HTML structure

```
<span class="ag-column-select-checkbox" role="presentation" ref="cbSelect">  

  <span class="ag-checkbox-checked" role="presentation">
    <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-checked"></span>
  </span> 

  <span class="ag-checkbox-unchecked ag-hidden" role="presentation">
    <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-unchecked"></span>
  </span>  

  <span class="ag-checkbox-indeterminate ag-hidden" role="presentation">
    <span class="ag-icon ag-icon-checkbox-indeterminate"></span>
  </span>  

  <span class="ag-checkbox-label" role="presentation"></span>

</span>
```

they're using spans, when you check those elements styling you can see they have images set up as background [like this one](http://data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTgiIGhlaWdodD0iMTgiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxOCAxOCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj48cGF0aCBkPSJNMTYgMEgyYTIgMiAwIDAgMC0yIDJ2MTRhMiAyIDAgMCAwIDIgMmgxNGEyIDIgMCAwIDAgMi0yVjJhMiAyIDAgMCAwLTItMnpNNyAxNEwyIDlsMS40MS0xLjQxTDcgMTEuMTdsNy41OS03LjU5TDE2IDVsLTkgOXoiIGZpbGw9IiNGRjQwODEiLz48L3N2Zz4=) that its being used for the `ag-icon-checkbox-checked` element.

They're using javascript to achieve this.

But here you can see an article and a codepen on how to customize checkboxes with css:

- [w3schools - How TO - Custom Checkbox](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp)
- [CodePen - Custom checkboxes CSS only](https://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/BiHzp)

Hope it helps,